# What is wrong with the following Python code?

Tags: python

Could any one help me to debug the following python code?

code is shown here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: using_tuple.py


zoo = ('python', 'elephant', 'penguin') # remember the parentheses are optional
print('Number of animals in the zoo is', len(zoo))

new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel')
print('Number of cages in the new zoo is', len(new_zoo))
print('All animals in new zoo are', new_zoo)
print('Animals brought from old zoo are', new_zoo[2])
print('Last animal brought from old zoo is', new_zoo[2][2])
print('Number of animals in the new zoo is', len(new_zoo)-1+len(new_zoo[2]))
```

Comment: There is no connection between zoo and new_zoo.  Assuming at least one animal has to be brought from zoo to new_zoo.  Also you have indexes out of bounds as python use a zero based index where the first item is [0]

Comment: At least two things need to be clarified: first, whether `'python'`, `'elephant'`, and `'penguin'` belong to the new zoo, that is, they have been brought from the old zoo; second, whether those three animals have been put in a single cage in the new zoo. Calculations and tuple accesses in `print()` calls are contradictory, swinging between different models of the new zoo. Without a further explanation of how you intend to model the new zoo with respect to the old zoo, it's quite impossible to guess exactly what the correct answers should be.

Comment: Is this your answer to the homework, or is the homework just to make this code work properly?

Comment: It would help to see the homework problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you combine old and new zoo?

Possibilities:

```
>>> new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel', zoo)
>>> new_zoo
('monkey', 'camel', ('python', 'elephant', 'penguin'))
>>> new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel') + zoo
>>> new_zoo
('monkey', 'camel', 'python', 'elephant', 'penguin')
```

Comment: I don't mean to combine old and new zoo. It happed that I can not successfully run these code.

Comment: @jervis the statement `new_zoo[2][2]` really suggests you assume option 1, that is, put zoo into new_zoo.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing in programming languages usually starts from zero, not one.
The length maybe 2, but the second element is with the index 1.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the old zoo to the new zoo.

Answer (score 0):

In this line: `print('Last animal brought from old zoo is', new_zoo[2][2])'

new_zoo[2][2] is invalid in your current code for 2 reasons:
1. Arrays are 0-indexed. new_zoo[2] refers to the 3rd element, not the 2nd.
2. Also, you will just be printing a character (specifically the 3rd character) of that zoo animal.

Answer (score -1):

The variable new_zoo has two elements and the number of elements starts from zero

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).